# facing problem with specific web scrapping

Tags: python, web-scraping

i am still learning web scrapping
however i am writing a code to scrape a specific web site and access its content
this web site :-

"https://tenders.etimad.sa/Qualification/QualificationsForVisitor"

how ever this code return an error
but on another this website

"https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=&a=hpb"

the code run correctly
I asked chat GPT and he replied that the website prevent anybody to access it content, how ever using "ScrapeStorm" the application succeed to reach the website content

so do i do any mistakes ? what i this ? and how to access the website content

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

#link of website
result = requests.get("https://tenders.etimad.sa/Qualification/QualificationsForVisitor")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml")
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `False` to the verify of requests. Here you go:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

#link of website
result = requests.get("https://tenders.etimad.sa/Qualification/QualificationsForVisitor", verify = False)
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

Outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link href="/Etimad-UI/assets/imgs/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link href="/Etimad-UI/assets/imgs/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link href="/Etimad-UI/assets/imgs/favicon.ico" rel="icon"/>
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<title>
      جميع دعوات التأهيل
   </title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport"/>
<!--     Fonts and icons     -->
<link href="/Etimad-UI/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
<link href="/Etimad-UI/assets/scss/Etimad/etd-style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Etimad-UI/assets/scss/Etimad/NewAddedStyle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/Etimad-UI/assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
      *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
         background-color: #29ad6f;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body class="landing-page sidebar-collapse RTL">
...
<script src="/Etimad-UI/assets/js/EUM-Files/adrum.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```